# 'Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class say apiConnecting where I check the for token expiry to redirect to login page

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sExpirtyTime))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/");
}
```

But the above code does not redirect to login page

I tried to change the status code and then redirect to login page

I have following code in global.asax file

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 302 &&
                Context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
    {
         //Context.Response.Clear();
         Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    }
}
```

in master layout I will redirect to login if status code is 401.
But above code returning error

> System.Web.HttpException: 'Server cannot set status after HTTP headers
>   have been sent

I have an alternate to do this checking in onactionexecuting and that is working, But I don't want to mix this code.

Can someone help me how to accomplish this

Thanks

Comment: How would you expect to be able to send the beginning of the request (the headers( at the end of the request?

Comment: Also, is your login page at `"~/"` or somewhere else? How do you authenticate?

Comment: I have login page at ~/, What I need like each controller make a web API request, and this class add access token and check refresh token, I have given the sample how I am redirectingh

Comment: Above code sample is working in my one project but somehow in current project it stays on page does not get redirected to login page